# python не видит библиотеку opencv

Tags: python, pip

Установил через pip библиотеку opencv. Пытаюсь импортировать из консоли получается без проблем библиотеку cv2, а когда пишу в IDE то она её подчеркивает красным, что мне и не нравится! кто знает как решается проблема? Прикрепил скриншот, с низу через консоль импортирую там видно что импорт работает!Устанавливал библиотеку через pip
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Откройте терминал, запустите питон и посмотрите версию установленной бибилиотеки: `> import cv2 \n print(cv2.__version__)`. Какая версия питона? Что Вы именно устанавливали при  помощи pip? Добавьте скрипт. Или точное название библиотеки. Попробуйте удалить opencv и установить её заново.

Comment: вывод такой - 3.3.0;  качал я файл opencv_python‑3.3.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl с сайта http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv. После этого я сделал pip install файл который скачал. Питон у меня версии 3.62. Не знаю важно это или нет я также качал numpy библиотеку с того же ресурса и тоже установил через pip. сейчас попробую удалить и установить  еще раз.

Comment: а выхода в интернет ваша машина не имеет? попробуйте pip install cv2...

Comment: Помогло , хотя не понятно все это, pip качал точно такой же файл как и я, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

используйте virtual env для избежания подобных ситуаций

Answer (score -2):

Иногда, при установке **openCV**, оказывается, что python его не видит. В связи с этим иногда помогает переустановка **openCV**. Если Вы работаете под системами ***nix**, то возможным решением может оказаться использовать `apt-get` вместо `pip`. Ещё одной причиной отказа работать может быть установка пакета не для нужной версии `python`. Попробуйте установить пакет при помощи `pip2` и `pip3`, если, конечно, у Вас есть **python2** и **python3** соответсвенно.